# Consuming azure devops feed during deployment of web app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pip, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am having a python flask app which is deployed on azure web app.
Recently we created a devops feed for common component and want to consume the same in webapp. For taking from private feed we use

```
PipAuthenticate@1
```

This woks fine while building the app. but at the time of deployment(in the AzureWebApp@1 task) since we do not have control on the build as it is done in antenv created by the above task, this leads to failure to recognize the private feed.

Is there a way to resolve this issue, I need to consume the private feed in azure devops during webapps deployment as well

Comment: In order to clarify the problem, please help confirm the following information:
1. Are you using build pipeline and release pipeline? If you use the release pipeline, please share its related definitions with me.
2. You mentioned "deployment", please share the relevant definitions with me.

Comment: In the process of azure pipeline, we usually generate an artifact by running the build pipeline, and then consume the artifact in the release pipeline. For more information on the release pipeline, please refer to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops